# Get Minimum Date value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I am trying to get the minimum value date if the column next to it has the word "before". I tried the following formula, but I am getting a value of 0. Am I missing something here?

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim a As String
    a = "before"
    j = 0
LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim MyArr() As Variant
ReDim MyArr(1 To LRow) As Variant
  
For i = 1 To LRow
 If VBA.InStr(Range("B" & i).Value, a) > 0 Then
        j = j + 1
        MyArr(j) = Range("A" & i).Value
  End If
Next i
   
    ReDim Preserve MyArr(1 To j)
    
Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(MyArr())

End Sub
```

Comment: `=MINIFS(A1:A5, B1:B5, "*before*")` should do the job without having to resort to a VBA UDF.

Comment: I am dealing with an ever expanding array, and need a vba solution. Your method , can it be written in terms of vba udf?

Comment: `MyArr(j) = CDbl(Range("A" & i).Value)` for whatever reason `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min()` doesn't seem to like dates.

Comment: @elyas: you can replace "A1:A5" by "A:A", then no need to worry about expanding arrays.

Comment: I tried, but I can't seem to insert the  "*before*".

Comment: `=MINIFS(A:A, B:B, "*before*")` will work fine and will also be faster than anything you can whip up in VBA.

Comment: Sub test()

   
Range("D1").Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(Range("A1:A5").Value, Range("B1:B5").Value, "*before*")

End Sub


Doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

Use `MINIFS`:

```
=MINIFS(A:A, B:B, "*before*")
```

With VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Range("D1").Value = WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(Range("A:A"), Range("B:B"), "*before*")
    Range("D1").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```